# Gram matrix of $A$ is equal to $A^T \bar{ A }$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, $( \vec{ a_1 }, \vec{ a_2 }, \ldots, \vec{ a_n } )$ and $A'$, the Gram matrix of $A$,  is a matrix having $\vec{ a_i } \cdot \vec{ a_j }$ as $(i,j)$ element.

How can we get $A'= A^T \bar{ A }$ ? ($A^t$ is the transpose of $A$ and $\bar{ A }$ is the complex conjugate of $A$.)

Comment: Try including your efforts in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that the dot product between two vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ is $\vec{v}^T \overline {\vec{w}}$, then it follows from the fact that given any two matrices $A$ and $B$, the $(i, j)$th element is the $i$th row of $A$ dotted with the $j$th column of $B$.

Note that if the dot product is simply $\vec{v}^T \vec{w}$, this property is not true (unless we're dealing with real matrices, in which case the complex conjugate is meaningless). Take
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ i & 1\end{bmatrix}, ~~A^T \overline{A} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ i & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
for example, which doesn't satisfy your property.

Answer (score 1):

That's matrix multiplication: "row times column".